# Alternate way of expressing spectral decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

My question:

Suppose $A\phi_i=\lambda_i\phi_i$ and $A^*\psi_i=\overline{\lambda_i}\psi_i$, for $i=1,\dots, n$ and that $\lambda_I \neq \lambda j$ for $i \neq j$. Prove that $A=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i P_i$, where $P_i=\phi_i\psi_i^*$ is a projection matrix. Note that $A$ is $n \times n$ and each eigenvalue has multiplicity 1.

my work:

I am familiar with the usual form of the spectral decomposition theorem but this is my first time seeing this. It seems that this is saying that $A$ can be written as the sum of its projections onto each of its eigenspaces?

I tried to form the matrix $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i \phi_i \psi_i^*$ and I was able to use the biorthogonality condition along with $A \phi=\lambda \phi$ to get the desired result. I am wondering if there is a method that avoids the long calculation.

The first part of this problem was to show that the eigenvectors of $A$ and $A^*$ form a biorthogonal set.

Comment: Is $n$ also the size of the matrix?  That is, does $A$ only have eigenvalues of multiplicity $1$?

Comment: yes, sorry I forgot to mention this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $A$ and $A^*$ have one-dimensional eigenspaces, it suffices to show that $A$ can be written in this form for *some* choice of $\phi_i,\psi_i$.  In particular, suppose that
$$
A = SDS^{-1}
$$
Let $\phi_i$ be the $i$th column of $S$ and $\psi_i$ the $i$th column of $(S^{-1})^*$.  We then have
$$
A = \pmatrix{\phi_1 & \cdots & \phi_n}
\pmatrix{\lambda_1\\&\ddots\\&&\lambda_n}
\pmatrix{\psi_1^*\\ \vdots \\ \psi_n^*}
$$
With block-matrix multiplication, we find
$$
A = \sum \lambda_i \phi_i\psi_i^*
$$
as desired.

Comment: why can $\psi_i$ be chosen to be the $i^{th}$ column of $(S^{-1})^*$? Actually, why is $(S^{-1})^*$ being used in place of $S^{*}$?

Comment: @user210552 note that $A^* = (S^{-1})^*\overline D S^*$.

Comment: ohhh thank you this makes sense now